# IOS Swift : TableViewController with inner TableView in a static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

[Comparison : left TableViewController : not Working ; right ViewController : working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkB4b.jpg)

I have a problème with the inner tableView in the left Controller  :
Because the left controller is a TableViewController with static cells it can't implement the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource protocols so I can't use the TableViewController class as the delegate of the inner tableView.

I created a class (InnerTVDelegate) that acts as the delegate of the inner tableView and i set the tableView delegate/datasource to an instance of InnerTVDelegate but it does not work .

Here are my classes :

import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var innerTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    innerTableView.delegate = InnerTVDelegate()
    innerTableView.dataSource = InnerTVDelegate()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

class InnerTVDelegate : NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InnerTVTableViewCell") as! InnerTVTableViewCell

    cell.mytextLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

}

What is wrong with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var innerTableView: UITableView!
    var tvDelegate:InnerTVDelegate()!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tvDelegate = InnerTVDelegate()
        innerTableView.delegate = tvDelegate
        innerTableView.dataSource = tvDelegate
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , it works :)
Can you explain me why 
you just declared the tvDelegate as instance variable.
Is it because i used 2 differents instances as delagate and dataSource ?

Comment: No. InnerTVDelegate() returning an autoreleased object. It is just getting released.